# WHY Tracert.exe command takes longer to display results while the browser displays the same page in seconds

Tags: networking

I am a newbie to networking.

I tried using the tracert.exe command to google.com
the results were displayed after 1 minute or so including the many hops.

Whereas if I type Google.com in my browser it takes less than 10 seconds to show the home page or infact any search results too are displayed in less than a minute(just to remove the cache & proxy doubts).

My question is, why is there such a difference in the time taken if the originator and destination are same.

Comment: In order to draw a conclusion from the fact that something didn't happen, you have to wait the longest it could possibly take for that thing to happen. Displaying a web page doesn't require drawing conclusions like that.

Comment: Don't know why there is a -1 even after stating this is a question from newbie

Comment: @bala, are you a professional acting as a system administrator?  Do you believe this is a system administration question?  Did you spend any time doing some homework, by looking up via Google how [traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) works, or how [web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) work?  Some of us are a bit picky here, we do expect you to do some research on your own first, and to review our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

You realize that the programming for display a website page is different than a tracert.  The speed in tracert is most likely due to all the DNS lookups/ICMP timeouts being processed for all the intermediate hosts involved in the trace.

Also in browsing you might be looking at your local cache in which case very little work / time needs to be done.

Thus this is normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you go to Google, you're just fetching data from Google.  Not stopping at every hop along the way to query those systems too (which tracert does).  And since some of those systems won't respond to ICMP queries, your tracert runs into timeouts, where as your connection to Google's web servers on a protocol they're intended to respond on does not.